# Signal mapping to composition possible?

Tags: autosar

In my current design I have several Com signals mapped to a single **atomic** SWC. I want to divide functionality into several SWC(s).
I have created a **composition** which now contains 3 SWCs.

My idea is to have the Com signals being connected to the ports of the **composition**. And from there via DELEGATION-SW-CONNECTOR(s) the signal shall be routed to the (internal) SWCs. Some signal may be needed by more than one SWC.

Unfortunaltely my RTE generation tools says

**"Com signals cannot be mapped to data elements of compositions"**

Q: Is this a general AUTOSAR limitation or a problem of my specific RTE product?

UPDATE: I have checked the manual of **another** RTE product which says:
*It is also possible to use a service connector between a port on a service component and a port on a **software composition**.*
So I guess the issue I encounter comes from a limitation of the specific RTE used in this project...

Answer (score 0):

Your use case looks accepted by AUTOSAR.
Just found the following into [AUTOSAR_TPS_SystemTemplate 22-11](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/standards/classic/22-11/AUTOSAR_TPS_SystemTemplate.pdf):

**[TPS_SYST_01036]** No additional Data Mappings in composition substructure
dWhen a CompositionSwComponentType is refined by a supplier the already existing DataMappings that refer to the CompositionSwComponentType shall not be
copied to the internal substructure.

Suppliers who add substructure to a CompositionSwComponentType by adding
SwComponentPrototypes and SwConnectors shall respect the predefined
DataMappings on the CompositionSwComponentType.
The OEM/Supplier Collaboration Scenario is described in chapter 13.1.

If you have time, you will find all your answer into Chapter 5.2